# Windows Form Designer isn't loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a Windows Form with code in it as well as some objects. However, when I go to open the file with the designer, it opens the source code. The Windows Form icon has dissapeared now, instead it shows the C# source icon.

[image: Solution Explorer]

If I try 'Open With...', the designer is not an option.

[image: Open With Window]

This wasn't like this at first, not sure why it is now. Any ideas? :-)

Visual Studio 2019 Community, Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you put some code before the class (delegate, enum, another class, another namespace...)? That prevents the designer to work well, thus you can move at the end, after the form class.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes, I have included [this](https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386) before the class.

Comment: You should add a new file, and preserve the gist, and add a comment with link if you want to be fair, instead of c/c in the form class...

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thanks for your feedback, after moving the code to the bottom it now works. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered now.

> Did you put some code before the class (delegate, enum, another class, another namespace...)? That prevents the designer to work well, thus you can move at the end, after the form class -@OliverRogier

Fixed my issue, thanks :)